# Refind Boot Manager can’t find any OS to boot

Tags: windows-10, refind

My rEFind boot manager can’t detect any OS to boot. For this reason, i can’t enter my Windows or something else.

Can someone help me?

Thank you very much.

[You guys can see my rEFind boot manager here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoNeF.jpg)

Comment: Do you have special reason to use this boot manager?

Comment: Yes, Im gonna dual boot my windows and linux OS.

Comment: `grub` support this on the fly. Just install Linux after Windows